# Mysql 8 metadata locks on foreign key tables during alter

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, table-locking

When I do `alter table` commands Im getting lots of dead locks. Where commands are `waiting for metadata lock` on tables that are not part of the alter table statement. The tables are linked through a foreign key but we are not changing the foreign key.

Is there a way to run alter tables without bringing mysql to its knees?

### Minimal Example

Given these two tables tables with a foreign key relationship.

```
create table parent(id int primary key);
create table child(
    id int primary key,
    `parent_id` int,
    constraint `parent_id_fk` foreign key (`parent_id`) references `parent` (`id`)
);
```

When a connection reads some data it acquires a metadata locks.

```
start transaction read only;
select * from child;
-- commit later
```

A seperate connection then tries to run an alter statement on the parent table. This wants a metadata lock on child even though we are not touching child or the id.

```
alter table parent add column x int null;
```

We can see these locks in

```
mysql> select * from performance_schema.metadata_locks ;
+-------------+--------------------+----------------+-------------+-----------------------+---------------------+---------------+-------------+--------------------+-----------------+----------------+
| OBJECT_TYPE | OBJECT_SCHEMA      | OBJECT_NAME    | COLUMN_NAME | OBJECT_INSTANCE_BEGIN | LOCK_TYPE           | LOCK_DURATION | LOCK_STATUS | SOURCE             | OWNER_THREAD_ID | OWNER_EVENT_ID |
+-------------+--------------------+----------------+-------------+-----------------------+---------------------+---------------+-------------+--------------------+-----------------+----------------+
| TABLE       | performance_schema | metadata_locks | NULL        |        47604062188640 | SHARED_READ         | TRANSACTION   | GRANTED     | sql_parse.cc:6213  |           24981 |             15 |
| GLOBAL      | NULL               | NULL           | NULL        |        47604063432464 | INTENTION_EXCLUSIVE | STATEMENT     | GRANTED     | sql_base.cc:5412   |           23547 |            607 |
| BACKUP LOCK | NULL               | NULL           | NULL        |        47604007764640 | INTENTION_EXCLUSIVE | TRANSACTION   | GRANTED     | sql_base.cc:5419   |           23547 |            607 |
| SCHEMA      | test               | NULL           | NULL        |        47604063432224 | INTENTION_EXCLUSIVE | TRANSACTION   | GRANTED     | sql_base.cc:5399   |           23547 |            607 |
| TABLE       | test               | parent         | NULL        |        47604068904032 | SHARED_UPGRADABLE   | TRANSACTION   | GRANTED     | sql_parse.cc:6213  |           23547 |            607 |
| TABLESPACE  | NULL               | test/parent    | NULL        |        47604068895072 | INTENTION_EXCLUSIVE | TRANSACTION   | GRANTED     | lock.cc:793        |           23547 |            607 |
| SCHEMA      | test               | NULL           | NULL        |        47604068902992 | INTENTION_EXCLUSIVE | STATEMENT     | GRANTED     | sql_table.cc:1117  |           23547 |            607 |
| TABLE       | test               | child          | NULL        |        47604007764800 | SHARED_UPGRADABLE   | STATEMENT     | GRANTED     | sql_table.cc:1109  |           23547 |            607 |
| TABLE       | test               | #sql-1f53_5ad9 | NULL        |        47604063517984 | EXCLUSIVE           | STATEMENT     | GRANTED     | sql_table.cc:16153 |           23547 |            607 |
| TABLE       | test               | child          | NULL        |        47604063429264 | EXCLUSIVE           | STATEMENT     | PENDING     | sql_table.cc:1109  |           23547 |            608 |
| TABLE       | test               | child          | NULL        |        47604010642320 | SHARED_READ         | TRANSACTION   | GRANTED     | sql_parse.cc:6213  |           24466 |            120 |
```

### Dead locks in production

In our production system which has more tables and foreign keys we are seeing dead locks, where the alter table acquires a locks for table A but cant get table B. Table B is locked by a thread that needs table A.
For us its a bit of a race condition, but its exacerbated by mysql needing a lock on *all* of the linked tables instead of just the one is is altering.

This seems to be new behaviour of mysql 8. I wish I didnt upgrade. We are on mysql 8.0.20 with innodb tables.

Is there a way to run these alters without locking up the database ? Ideally I want to keep my foreign keys and I dont want to use a migration manager like Percona. My tables arent even that big.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To make your ALTER TABLE statement do no locking, or return an error if the operations being performed are not possible without locking, do:

```
ALTER TABLE ..., LOCK=NONE;
```

Comment: Hi, this doesnt seem to work in this case. It seems to ignore it. Im not sure the reason maybe it ignores metadata locks ?

Comment: huh; does replacing the `*` with a list of columns help?  I don't have any other ideas

Comment: yeah, maybe switch to a better database, PostgreSQL has tools to help :-) https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL . locks are used on alters but it's well documented and there are fairly easy work arounds

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the new metadata locking from MySQL 8, which now [extends to foreign keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/metadata-locking.html#:%7E:text=Metadata%20locks%20are%20extended%2C%20as,while%20updating%20foreign%20key%20metadata.).

You can try setting `max_write_lock_count` to a lower number. There are more details in [this post](https://www.percona.com/blog/alters-foreign-keys-and-metadata-locks-oh-my/).

We tried this approach, which worked for some things, like `DROP TABLE`, but didn't work with `ADD FOREIGN KEY`.